# Swift 4 multi dimensional array or struct?

Tags: swift, class, struct

I'm creating a table viewcell.  this viewcell will show hotel and relative rooms .
to do that I created 2 classes to define hotel and rooms. each of 2 classes represent the relative object. example: 
hotel: services, position, lat, lang , description
room:  bed_type, people, Availability

I know need now to create a structure or array or whatever that act like a three  so basically so basically , for each hotel I can have more than one available room.

I was looking using an 2d array of any object as first solution but I don't know If this is best way to solve the problem.

ideally best would be to later can access object in an easy way...

my first second idea is to use a struct like this

```
   struct SearchResults{
        var Hotel: HotelModel
        var Rooms: [RoomModel]

    }
```

any suggestion is welcome

Comment: it's up to you. You can create rooms as a part of your Hotel class. thus no need of third Struct SearchResults.

Comment: forgot...   then create an array of SearchResults as: results = [Searchresults]

Comment: side note: variable names should start from lower case

Comment: I agree with @SahilManchanda, add a rooms array to your HotelModel class, `var rooms: [RoomModel]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can model your data.

Just create a `Hotel` model that contains an `array of Room` as its property.

```
struct Hotel {
    var rooms: [Room]
}

struct Room {
    //your properties...
}
```

Now, instead of using an extra `SearchResults` model, you can simply use a `array of Hotel`, i.e.

```
var results: [Hotel]
```